# Changing MySQL password in WHM

Tags: mysql, cpanel

When resetting an account password in WHM, I get a checkbox with this option:  "`Sync MySQL password with account password`."

If an account has multiple MySQL databases, what password is it going to change?

I did a test on a WordPress site and noticed that the MySQL password did not change, so I'm curious as to what this setting does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically used to Update the cPanel User's Password to Restore Database Access. Internally it fires following:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/restoregrants --cpuser=$cpuser --db={mysql, pg} --dbuser=$dbuser
```

or

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/restoregrants --cpuser=$cpuser --db={mysql, pg}  --all
```

where,

- $cpuser is cPanel username,
  and
- $dbuser is database user whose privileges you wish to restore.

Refer [this](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/RestoringDatabaseAccess) for complete detail.

Comment: Hmmm...given your answer, under what circumstance would you choose NOT to sync the passwords?

Comment: Webmasters choose to sync for restoring database access otherwise not. Its a recovery measure.